# How to install tensorflow 0.10.0 on linux?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I want to install 0.10.0 on linux for gpu.
In the tensorflow page it shows how to install 0.11.

I tried replacing 0.11 with 0.10 as follows:

Instead of

```
export  TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

export  TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But i got and HTTP error 404.

How can i install tensorflow 0.10 for python 2.7 linux 64 big, for gpu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the Version dropdown menu to select the r0.10 version

[image]

And then copy the URL:

```
#Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

The above methods doesn't work with the current TensorFlow website. In the latest iteration, we dont have a method to change the version from the UI.

**Instead** we can get the path of a specific version by running:

`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow |xmllint --format - | grep 0.10.0rc0 | grep .whl`

Here, I am looking for version `0.10.0rc0`

**Output**:

```
<Key>linux/cpu/debian/jessie/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl</Key>
<Key>mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl</Key>
<Key>mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl</Key>
<Key>mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl</Key>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install it with anaconda 
`conda create -n tensorflow010 tensorflow=0.10`,
but I am not sure whether this includes GPU computation.